# Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined with onchange

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to access to `Update_Price` function in JavaScript file when I make any changing on `select` tag, but unfortunately the Uncaught Reference Error appear. This is my code:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Form-validation.js"></script>
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select class="Booking-Form-Group" id="combo-box"  onchange="Update_Price()">
          <option value="1">Single Room</option>
          <option value="2">Double Room</option>
          <option value="3">Twin Room  </option>
          <option value="4">Family Room</option>
          <option value="5">Standard Room</option>
          <option value="6">Meeting Hall</option>
          <option value="7">Conference Room</option>
      </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my JavaScript code.

```
function Update_Price(){

    alert('Warning');

    var combo = document.getElementById('combo-box');
    var index = combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].value;

    var value = 0;
    if (index == 1){
        value = 15;
    }
    else if(index == 2 || index == 3){
        value = 25;
    }
    else if(index == 4){
        value = 40;
    }
    else if(index == 5){
        value = 20;
    }
    else{
        value = 60;
    }
    alert(value);

    document.getElementById('price').innerHTML='Total Price is: '.value;

}
```

Comment: is your JS code inside the `Form-validation.js`?

Comment: change `document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = 'Total Price is: '.value;` to `document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = 'Total Price is: '+value;`

Comment: put your `script` tag to the bottom of `body`

Comment: There is an extra </script> tag, doubt that is really hurting things though

Comment: @gurvinder372  yes it is inside Form-validation.js

Comment: @KarmelZaidan can you share the contents of Form-validation? It appears as if `Update_Price` is not defined in global context.

Comment: thank you everybody, i fixed the error by putting the script tag at the bottom of body

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is this line

```
document.getElementById('price').innerHTML='Total Price is: '.value;
```

It should have a concatenation operator `+` instead of `.`

```
document.getElementById('price').innerHTML='Total Price is: ' + value;
```

Comment: That's one problem, but it's not what's causing the error.

Comment: @AndyE you are right. It appears as if `Update_Price` is not defined at global level. Waiting for OP to update